# Netbeans @Inject CDI Event warning

Tags: java, netbeans, cdi

I'm trying to use event mechanism provided by CDI in my Java EE application. However, when I try to inject the CDI event, I'm getting this warning in Netbeans 7.4:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here (yes, I have beans.xml) or is this a Netbeans bug? Because the whole code works great on my testing Glassfish v4 server.
Thanks for any advice

Comment: I found this issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231507, which is maybe the source of my problems.

Comment: Does this warning stops you from running the program ? if not then i wouldn't bother with it.